Why login in ASP.NET Core with React project results in an 404 error?
I try to implement authorization with the SPA project. I created the project and published it on GitHub.
Project.cs
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ReactApp1.Server.Data;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ReactTypeScriptApp1.Server
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' not found.");

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();
             
            app.UseDefaultFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app/*.MapGroup("/account")*/.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

            app.MapPost("/logout", async (SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) =>
            {

                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                return Results.Ok();

            }).RequireAuthorization();

            app.MapGet("/pingauth", (ClaimsPrincipal user) =>
            {
                var email = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email); // get the user's email from the claim
                return Results.Json(new { Email = email }); ; // return the email as a plain text response
            }).RequireAuthorization();


            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

login.tsx
    import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
    // state variables for email and passwords
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
    const [rememberme, setRememberme] = useState<boolean>(false);
    // state variable for error messages
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // handle change events for input fields
    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        if (name === "email") setEmail(value);
        if (name === "password") setPassword(value);
        if (name === "rememberme") setRememberme(e.target.checked);
    };

    const handleRegisterClick = () => {
        navigate("/register");
    }

    // handle submit event for the form
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // validate email and passwords
        if (!email || !password) {
            setError("Please fill in all fields.");
        } else {
            // clear error message
            setError("");
            // post data to the /register api

            var loginurl = "";
            if (rememberme == true) {
                loginurl = "/login?useCookies=true";
            }
            else {
                loginurl = "/login?useSessionCookies=true";
            }

            //loginurl = loginurl + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
            fetch(loginurl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                }),
            }).then((data) => {
                // handle success or error from the server
                console.log(data);
                if (data.ok) {
                    setError("Successful Login.");
                    window.location.href = '/';
                }
                else
                    setError("Error Logging In.");

            }).catch((error) => {
                // handle network error
                console.error(error);
                setError("Error Logging in.");
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="containerbox">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label className="forminput" htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="rememberme"
                        name="rememberme"
                        checked={rememberme}
                        onChange={handleChange} /><span>Remember Me</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={handleRegisterClick}>Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;

https://github.com/hmahdavi921/ReactTypeScriptApp1
Of course, when I try from Swagger, it works correctly, but when I call the login API from another browser, I get a 404 error.
What is the problem?

Hi @hmahdavi, i have tested your project and works fine to call the login api from browser address bar. What is your request url?

Be sure your request url is: https://localhost:5173/login. Cause your set the spa server url in ReactTypeScriptApp1.Server project file like below:
<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:5173</SpaProxyServerUrl>

